# Do you know of any Flex Point and Click game Libraries?

Tags: apache-flex

I'm looking for a game library for Flex that supports such features as:

- Movement
- Inventory
- Items

Does anyone know of any libraries that might be suitable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Fixel](http://flixel.org/), which is an ActionScript game library. You could also try the [Flash Adventure Game Tutorial](http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/blog/archive/2009/11/22/create-your-own-flash-adventure-game.aspx), which shows you how to create a point and click game with Flex.

[image]